# Linq: GroupBy vs Distinct

Tags: c#, linq

I've been trying to get a Linq query to return distinct values from a collection. I've found two ways to go about it; either use GroupBy or Distinct.
I know that Distinct was made for the job but I have to implement IEquatable on the object.

I tried GroupBy and that worked just fine. I want to know if using Distinct vs GroupBy has a distinct performance advantage.

Comment: Have you tried to compare the performance of the two approaches yourself using real data?

Comment: Broadly speaking, I'd expect similar performance, but don't let that stop you from making your own measurements!

Comment: No, Actually! I think I'll do that and get back to you :) and maybe answer my own question! thanks guys!

Comment: Just pick one. If you find that your application is being slowed down by this particular bit of code then go back and look into performance then.

Comment: Unless you're doing boatloads upon boatloads of queries, I'd say that performance doesn't matter. Use whichever is more _correct_ for your code's _intent_. Only benchmark/change/optimize _if_ and _when_ you have identified actual measurable performance bottlenecks.

Comment: That being said, if I had to guess, I'd say `Distinct` is probably faster. Even without implementing `IEquatable`, it should work fine using object reference equality and all it does is build a single `HashSet` under the covers throwing away duplicates. `GroupBy` will also be building sub-collections for each grouping and keep every duplicate. But I wouldn't act on this assumption without a benchmark. (Also, this might change depending on how you're using it; this is, I'm assuming, an in-memory collection. Performance may likely differ if it's a LINQ-to-SQL or Entities query)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: well the question came up just out of curiosity. I think groupby works fine for now, but maybe later I'll tinker around with distinct.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Distinct()` will compare entire objects in collection (for reference types you need GetHashCode and Equals to be overridden). It will enumerate items and just add them to set. Simple and fast. Something like:

```
Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);

foreach (TSource tSource in source)
{
     if (!set.Add(tSource))
          continue;

     yield return tSource;
}
```

`GroupBy()` allows you to group object by some key. In this case keys will be compared. It will need to execute key selector lambda for each item in collection. Also it will need to create grouping for each distinct key and add each item in collection to its group:

```
Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector = x => x;

<TKey, TElement> lookup = new Lookup<TKey, TElement>(comparer);
foreach (TSource tSource in source)
{
     TKey key = keySelector(tSource);

     // simplified pseudo-code
     if (!lookup.Contains(key))
          lookup.Add(new Grouping(key)); 

     lookup[key].Add(elementSelector(tSource));
}

foreach(IGrouping<TKey, TElement> grouping in lookup)
    yield return grouping;
```

So, I think `GroupBy()` is not that fast as simple `Distict()`.

Comment: I know this is old, but I just ran a test (and after that googled it and came by this page) where I need the unique values of only one column in a table with 100k items. For the groupby I just group by that column and I'll have the results. For the distinct I first select that column and than do a distinct on the remainder. Result: distinct took 37 seconds. Groupby took 30 seconds.

Comment: @JonKoeter Do you have a link?

Comment: @Cees It was a test I ran on my own computer, so no.

Comment: I just ran a distinct vs group by, both with an order by clause, and the result was 663ms for distinct vs 551ms for group by, so similar result to @JonKoeter. This was using vb.net in VS 2017

Comment: @user2728841 how many times did you run your tests? In what order? What was the shape of the test data - all items are same, or all items are different? How many items did you have - ten or thousand? I don't see a case when GroupBy should be faster than Distinct. It would be interesting to see such a case.

Comment: I tried two structures, one was a list of an internal class, and grouped by five string attributes of that class. I also tried with list(of string). I have not kept the code but the performance seemed consistent regardless of these two types. I did not test any other types - i.e. I only ran the test for my benefit to get the fastest solution, as opposed to trying to find a conclusive answer for everyone :) The test included 3 different list(of string) with between 5000 and 25000 items. the class list contained 53000 items

Comment: @user2728841 but how did you use Distinct if you used only five attributes for grouping. Did you override GetHasCode and Equals of your class?

Comment: VB linq has a distinct keyword that you put at the end of the select statement, that allows distinct on multiple columns the same as sql server does

Comment: @user2728841 so maybe your test results are VB-related?

Comment: Yes, I didn't try the c# equivalent or indeed the .Distinct() method