# How can I check if the same Date is already in a List?

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I have a List of DateTimes (with Times and Dates) and now need a mothod to get all the unique days out of it into a seperate List
Example:

```
[1.1.2015 12:34]    [1.1.2015 12:34]   [1.1.2015 12:34]
[1.2.2015 4:34]     [1.2.2015 2:34]     [1.2.2015 1:34]
[1.3.2015 8:34]     [1.3.2015 1:34]     [1.6.2015 2:34]
```

Needs to be Turned into:

```
[1.1.2015 0:0]    [1.2.2015 0:0]    [1.3.2015 0:0]    [1.6.2015 0:0]
```

How Do I do this?

Comment: I'd prefer  a `HashSet<DateTime>`: `var uniqueDates = new HashSet<DateTime>(list.Select(dt => dt.Date));`. It is more efficient in lookups if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group them on `Date` property and project all keys:

```
var dates = dateandTimes.GroupBy(x=> x.Date)
                        .Select(x=>x.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: This is less efficient that the other answer and also not as clear(imo).

Comment: @TimSchmelter but GroupBy suits this scenario, I would do groupby

Comment: Yes, it works. But if i want distinct dates i select the date and then use `Distinct`. If i want group of dates i use `GroupBy`. The result is the same since you only use the `Key` property. But the intent is not so clear. `Groupby` is also a little bit more heavy than `Distinct` since it needs to create new objects. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22066584/284240

Comment: Depends on the size of the collection and how often you use this code. Needs also more memory.

Answer (score 8):

DateTime.Date and [Enumrable.Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is an option (assuming you don't need to keep order):

```
var dates = dateAndTimes.Select(d => d.Date).Distinct().ToList();
```

`Distinct` may, but does not have to preserve order of items (I believe current implementations will keep order).

If you need to *formally* guarantee original order - either re-sort (`OrderBy`) if list is already sorted, or iterate items in the original list and add to new list once that are not already in the list (similar to what `Distinct` does internally, but with guaranteed behavior of your code).

Note that as per Tim Schmelter comment for keeping order of items using something like `newList.Contains(itemAboutToBeAdded)` is very slow (and awkward as you'd need to check if item is in sequence that is currently being constructed), using regular `foreach` similar to following would math O(n) performance provided by `Distinct` along with *formal* order guarantee:

```
 var dates = dateAndTimes.Select(d => d.Date);
 var alreadyInList = new HashSet<DateTime>();
 var datesInSameOrder = new List<DateTime>();
 foreach(var date in dates)
 {
    if (!alreadyInList.Contains(date))
    {
        alreadyInList.Add(date);
        datesInSameOrder.Add(date);
    }
 }
```

Shorter version can be written to rely on the fact that `HashSet.Add` returns `false` if item is already present:

```
var alreadyInList = new HashSet<DateTime>();
var datesInSameOrder = dates.Where(date => alreadyInList.Add(date)).ToList();
```

or even if relying on implementation details for order of items in `HashSet` to be the same as order of `Add` calls (formally order is not defined, so use at own risk, `Distinct` have the same behavior - so no benefit):

```
 var datesInSameOrder = new HashSet<DateTime>(dates).ToList();
```

Comment: _" or use Where to filter out elements that are already present"_  that would be a very  inefficient solution, `Distinct` is much better.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Good point... Sounded better (also I realized code would look completely ridiculous with filtering on sequence that is being built at the same time) - added somewhat more reasonable explanation.

Comment: You don't need to check if the set contains the date, just add it, if it was already inside `Add` returns `false`: `bool isNew = alreadyInList.Add(date);`, you could also use `alreadyInList.ToList()` to create the list. However, the `foreach` is not more efficient than you first approach since `Distinct` also uses a set.

Comment: @TimSchmelter good point on `HashSet.Add`... but I would not recommend `alreadyInList.ToList()` as `HashSet` *formally* does not guarantee order.