# Use Datatype List<Part> for Retrieving the Result

Tags: c#, linq

Goal:
Retrieve the variable ff as a datatype `List<Part>` after executing the code

```
parts.GroupBy(b => new { b.PartName, b.PartId }).ToList();
```

The result should be three unique Part

Problem:
I tried a find solution but in the end it always end as the following code.

```
    List<Part> parts = new List<Part>();

    // Add parts to the list.
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "crank arm", PartId = 1234 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "crank arm", PartId = 1234 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "chain ring", PartId = 1334 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "regularseat", PartId = 1434 });



    var ff = parts.GroupBy(b => new { b.PartName, b.PartId }).ToList();
```

Thank you!

Comment: you want distinct parts?

Comment: MMK - yes, you are right and also retrieve the value in the datatype List<Part>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `Select` statement:

```
List<Part> ff = parts
    .GroupBy(b => new { b.PartName, b.PartId })
    .Select(g => new Part
    {
        PartName = g.Key.PartName
        PartId = g.Key.PartId
    })
    .ToList();
```

### Update

If your goal is just select distinc `Part` objects, then the `GroupBy` may be slower than `Distinct` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22066584/1380428)). But you have to test and see yourself.
If you want to use `Distinct` then you have to create equality comparer by implementing [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. Be sure to check [JonSkeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/1380428) for good `GetHashCode` method in case you choosed `Distinct`.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: @HelloWorld, you are welcome, be sure to check updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the first element from each group with Select. Then you have a flat list of Parts.

```
List<Part> parts = new List<Part>();

// Add parts to the list.
parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "crank arm", PartId = 1234 });
parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "crank arm", PartId = 1234 });
parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "chain ring", PartId = 1334 });
parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "regularseat", PartId = 1434 });



var ff = parts.GroupBy(b => new { b.PartName, b.PartId }).Select(group => group.First()).ToList();
```