# Entity Framework Core using select and group by

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to use `select` and `groupby` in my query

```
_context.UserChart_Tbl
        .Where(uc => uc.UserID == "6")
        .GroupBy(g => g.OrgnizationID)
        .Select(g => g.OrgnizationID)
        .ToArray();
```

But I get an error in `select`

> Error CS1061  'IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'OrgnizationID' and no accessible extension method 'OrgnizationID' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I solve this problem?

**Update**

Error Solved by this code

```
_context.UserChart_Tbl
          .Where(uc => uc.UserID == u.Id)
          .GroupBy(g => g.OrgnizationID)
          .Select(g => g.Key).ToArray()
```

**Complete Code**

```
    public List<DoctorDropDoenViewModel> DoctorDropDown()
    {
        var query = (from u in _context.Users
                     join
                     UR in _context.UserRoles on u.Id equals UR.UserId
                     join
                     D in _context.Doctor_Tbl on u.Id equals D.DoctorUserId
                     where UR.PolicyID == 4

                     select new DoctorDropDoenViewModel()
                     {
                         DoctorID = u.Id,
                         DoctorFullName = u.FirstName + " " + u.Family,
                         OrgID = _context.UserChart_Tbl.Where(uc => uc.UserID == u.Id)
                         .GroupBy(g => g.OrgnizationID).Select(g => g.Key).ToArray()
                     });


      return query.ToList();
    }
```

And

```
public class DoctorDropDoenViewModel
{
    public string DoctorID { get; set; }
    public string DoctorFullName { get; set; }
    public int[] OrgID { get; set; }
}
```

`DoctorID` can have several `OrgID` Which may also be duplicates. I want to display duplicates only once. For this purpose i use `Distinct` and `Group By`.

But `Group By` not working

[image]

Comment: What is expected result here? Can you give us some sample data and expected output so that we can try out by our self and give you exact solution instead of suggesting some common human errors

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I updated question and added complete details

Comment: Here `.Distinct()` will use to get unique values of `OrgID` not `GroupBy`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066346/linq-groupby-vs-distinct

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar But `Distinct` not working!

Comment: kindly check my answer, it might help you

Answer (score 1):

Wwhen you are grouping items property which you are using for group is going to 'Key' of the group. Replace `Select(g => g.OrgnizationID)` with `Select(g => g.Key)` it should help.

Answer (score 0):

To get distinct elements from `OrganizationID` array, you need not to perform GroupBy, you have to create new dynamic object using `.Select()` method.

Try below solution, this might help you

```
public List<DoctorDropDoenViewModel> DoctorDropDown()
{
    var query = (from u in _context.Users
                 join
                 UR in _context.UserRoles on u.Id equals UR.UserId
                 join
                 D in _context.Doctor_Tbl on u.Id equals D.DoctorUserId
                 where UR.PolicyID == 4

                 select new DoctorDropDoenViewModel()
                 {
                     DoctorID = u.Id,
                     DoctorFullName = u.FirstName + " " + u.Family,
                     OrgID = _context.UserChart_Tbl
                     .Where(uc => uc.UserID == u.Id)
                     .Select(g => g.OrgnizationID)  //Select only OrganizationID from complete object
                     .Distinct()   //Remove duplicates.
                     .ToArray()    //Convert IEnumerable<T> to Array
                 });


  return query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
_context.UserChart_Tbl.Where(uc => uc.UserID == u.Id)
.Where(x=>x.DoctorID==1).Select(g => g.OrgnizationID).Distinct().ToArray()}
```